# Images margin style on Opera looking out of place

Tags: html, css, opera

I have two images out of my whole website that look out of place only on Opera. I was wondering if there was a way I could add padding or a margin on top of the images to style them within Opera only.

Please let me know if there are any specific tags I can use within Opera only.

Thanks

Edit:

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:10000), not all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
.logo_style {
margin-top:-40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this used to work well however the answer is normally there is a non hack way to fix the problem

```
@media not screen and (1) {
.yourClass {background:red} /* OP 11 */
}
@media not screen and (orientation) {
.yourClass {background:green} /* for the earlier versions of Opera that pick the first media query's rule + chrome/safari */
}
```

Comment: Edited with the only other way ive seen